# Tripos Type Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This is an old calculus question:

Integrate
$$\int x^{-2n-2}(1-x)^n(1-cx)^ndx$$ it comes from Edwards Treatise on Integral Calculus Vol I, pg. 65 and is designated as [Oxford I.P. 1917].

I guess my question is what do they have in mind as a solution to this ? Are they expecting a closed form ?

My solution is to expand the $1-cx$ factor to get $(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k} \int\frac{x^k(1-x)^n}{x^{2n+2}}dx$ as the coefficient of $c^k$. This in turn can be integrated by the binomial theorem as
$\sum_{l=0}^n(-1)^{k+l}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{l}\frac{1}{2n-l-k+1}x^{-2n+k+l-1}$.
This almost seems too simple minded. But maybe it was what they intended. Any opinions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral can be written as a simple summation. To simplify, we change $y=1/x$ to write
\begin{align}
 I_n=&\int x^{-2n-2}(1-x)^n(1-cx)^n\,dx\\
 &=-\int (y-1)^n(y-c)^n\,dy
\end{align}
and to have a symmetric expression, changing $y=z+(c+1)/2$ gives
\begin{align}
 I_n&=-\int \left( z^2-\left( \frac{c-1}{2} \right)^2 \right)^n\,dz
\end{align}
Now, expanding the polynomial,
\begin{align}
 I_n&=-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{2k+1}\left( \frac{c-1}{2} \right)^{2n-2k}z^{2k+1}+C\\
 &=(-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\left( \frac{c-1}{2} \right)^{2n-2k}\left(1-\frac{(c+1)x}{2} \right)^{2k+1}x^{-2k-1}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica says:

$$\frac{(c-1) (1-x)^{n+1} x^{-2 n} (1-c x)^{n-1} \left(\frac{(c-1) x}{c x-1}\right)^{2 n}
   \, _2F_1\left(n+1,2 (n+1);n+2;\frac{x-1}{c x-1}\right)}{n+1}$$

I am not sure if this is the sort of thing they would want.

Comment: Yeah, well mathematica would say that. :-)  Not sure what $F_1$ is but I assume it is some variant of the hypergeometric function. Probably this is not the intended solution. But +1.

Comment: The function is the hypergeometric 2F1, which is a pretty common animal, though in many case it CAN be simplified to elementary functions. But it is possible that the exam here just wanted to test for understanding of hypergeometric...

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts, it can be shown that the integrals $I_n$ have the following property: $$I_n= (1-x)^n(1-cx)^n(\frac{x^{-2n-1}}{-2n-1}) + \frac{nc+n}{-2n-1}\int x^{-2n-1}(1-x)^{n-1}(1-cx)^{n-1}dx - \frac{2nc}{2n-1}I_{n-1} $$
That leftover integral does not exactly match the form of an $I_k$, but it is close. To me, it's concievable that $J_n = \int x^{-2n-1}(1-x)^{n-1}(1-cx)^{n-1}dx$ has a decomposition which will look similar to the above but with one of the $I_n$ appearing in the middle and $J_{n-1}$ at the end.

Maybe it is possible to solve the two recurrances, or perhaps the two relationships themselves would suffice for an answer.

Comment: Yes, that was my approach at first. But I have been unable to proceed further. It just seems to turn into a mess. That is why I suggest the other way.